# How to get selected filepath in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, relative-path, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js for uploading files. Now I want to do some additional validation for some files. But I didn't found a way to get the absolute path of selected file. Please anyone tell me whether there have any way to get the file path.

This is the file array returned by dropzone when we add a file

```
accepted: true
lastModifiedDate: Wed Dec 17 2014 13:01:03 GMT+0530 (IST)
name: "xxxxxx.pdf"
previewElement: div.dz-preview.dz-file-preview.dz-processing
previewTemplate: div.dz-preview.dz-file-preview.dz-processing
processing: true
size: 407552
status: "uploading"
type: "application/pdf"
upload: ObjectwebkitRelativePath: ""
xhr: XMLHttpRequest
__proto__: File
```

Comment: did you find an answer to this? I have the exact same question...

Comment: @CharlesA No, I didn't.

Comment: thanks. fwiw, I managed to solve my problem - which was how to resend the file a second time using additional parameters - by using processFile() command. Not sure it'll help in your case though

Comment: @CharlesA it is better if you write your solution as an answer. That may help someone in the future.

Comment: thanks. I didn't do that because it doesn't solve your problem!

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The full path comes through in the POST data:

```
Dropzone.options.yourDropzoneID = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data) {
        if(file.fullPath){
            data.append("fullPath", file.fullPath);
        }
    });
  }
};
```